# Two-column list: different column widths

Tags: lists, two-column, width

I wish to create a two-column list. One side of the list will contain relatively short items (1-2 short words) and the other side will have longer items (4-5 short-to-long words).

For example:

```
1. Item 1      4. This is item number 4
2. Item 2      5. This is item number 5
3. Item 3      6. This is item number 6
```

However, my code (below) using the `multicol` package causes the widths of both columns to be the same size, causing the left column to have too much room and the right column too little room (i.e. the text spans 2 lines).

How can I adjust the widths of the columns so that the first column is smaller than the right column?

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
        \item This is item number 4
        \item This is item number 5
        \item This is item number 6
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
```

Answer (score 19):

A simplistic solution could be to use two `minipage` environments rather than two columns, e.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}   
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
    \item This is item number 4
    \item This is item number 5
    \item This is item number 6       
  \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

You may also want to look at [How can I create a two-column layout with different widths (and texts) for the two columns?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4178/how-can-i-create-a-two-column-layout-with-different-widths-and-texts-for-the-tw)

Comment: Using [t] with a minipage will align it to the top, which might be desired if the columns are of different height.