# How do I prevent \section from breaking vwcol?

Tags: sectioning

Here is a minimal example that **works**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{vwcol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \begin{vwcol}[widths={0.6,0.4},sep=1.0cm,justify=flush,rule=0pt,indent=1em]
    \lipsum[1-3]
  \end{vwcol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I add `\section`, things get messed up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{vwcol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \begin{vwcol}[widths={0.6,0.4},sep=1.0cm,justify=flush,rule=0pt,indent=1em]
    \section{A Section Header}
    \lipsum[1-3]
  \end{vwcol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My guess is that `\section` is somehow asserting its width (and thus the first column's width) across the whole page, while the second column continues to compute its width based on the erroneous first's.

How can I fix this?

Comment: In fact, the `itemize` environment appears broken too, each item not respecting the column's width, but simply overflowing (presumably to the article width).

Comment: I suspect vwcol is a bit fragile.  I give it kudos for handling the paragraph breaking between two widths.

Comment: The package documentation actually says that you can't stick stuff in besides text.

Comment: May I know why you use this package `vwcol`? As there are many alternatives are available, e.g., `multicols` `paracol`, etc.

Comment: @MadyYuvi - I don't remember to be honest, but likely I was trying to use a template I found and liked (because I really am not familiar with TeX) and didn't know how to replace fundamental pieces of it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm not familiar with the package `\usepackage{vwcol}` what you are using, but if you want your text be in two column format, then you have some alternatives to meet the expactation.

**Method 1**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \section{A Section Header}
    \lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

**Method 2**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{A Section Header}
    \lipsum[1-6]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with `minipage`. Unfortunately it meant manually splitting up the content between two columns, rather than flowing, but it works.

More information at [Two-column list: different column widths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30569/29397).

Comment: Have you tried this solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89721/different-column-widths-using-multicol