# How to create a document with asymmetrical discontinuous columns?

Tags: two-column

I am trying to create a document that has two discontinuous and asymmetrical width columns with a dividing line vertically separating the columns, which extend above and below the text. The basic format would look something like this:

[image]

I've attempted to implement several ideas, but the closest I can get is with this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
dolor sit amet \\
nisi ut aliquip \\
non proident, sunt \\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The output looks something like this:

[image]

The main problem with my current solution is spacing. I attempted to insert the vertical line by making a new minipage and using tikz to generate the line, but three minipages seems to create alignment havoc. Can anyone help with a possible solution as to how I can generate the desired formatting from my drawing? Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a two-column layout with different widths (and texts) for the two columns?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4178/how-can-i-create-a-two-column-layout-with-different-widths-and-texts-for-the-t)

Comment: is this for just one page, or is it continuous for multiple pages, with the columns switching position on opposite pages?

Comment: The columns should not switch position on multiple pages. Ideally, if the text in the right column did not fit on one page, it would continue over to the right column on the next page. On the second page the left column would then be empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a tabular environment. In your case a `tabularx`-environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X@{}}
dolor sit amet \newline
nisi ut aliquip\newline
non proident, sunt 
&
\lipsum[1] \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]