# Layout with captions in margin and margin notes

Tags: captions, margins, marginpar

*Questions summed up below!*

I want to convert a number of old (read: ugly self-coded html) tutorials into pdfs. They are still read by people, so I think it's worth the effort. The other reasons:

- readers repeatedly asked for a printable version, for side-reading;
- they want to print them out to make notes and drawings (I could also interpret this as a demand for rephrasing, but I don't.);
- I want to use what I have learned about typography.

My approach starts with the demand for space for personal notes. They will probably go into the margin, because the margin usually provides some space. The tutorials are aimed at beginners in the subject, and a lot of the content is extremely simplified. This calls for inline notes, footnotes or marginal notes. I want a wide margin for the readers' personal notes, and I also want to use the margin for notes in the tutorial.

Now that the margin is wide, I can also place figure and table captions (I need both!) in the margin, and this is where I'm stuck. I've tried Will Robertson's suggestion from [this Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/margin-figures-captions), but the marginal caption is placed *on top* of the text. The code below is his, but turned in to an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\margincaption[1]{%
  \par
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\caption{#1}}}
  \@tempdima=\dimexpr\ht\@tempboxa+\dp\@tempboxa\relax
  \par\null\hfill\usebox\@tempboxa\par
  \vspace*{\dimexpr-\@tempdima-\baselineskip\relax}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[tp]
\rule{\textwidth}{1em}
\margincaption{A black long line with lots of explanation so it fills up some space.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I have tried ConTeXt for this, but the caption setting `rightmargin` produces no caption at all. I have asked the mailing list, but I've got the impression that it might be possible with pdfLaTeX (or XeTeX, or luaLaTeX) as well.

Yet another issue pops up when I need to include long lines of example code. The margin is wide, so the main text area is narrower than usual, which could lead to collisions. Anyway, is there a way to include over-long lines without generating an overfull hbox warning? This is a minor issue though - long lines *can* be broken.

- How can I place figure and table captions in the margin?
- How can I include single lines, extending into the margin, without producing collosions?
- If you have the impression that my layout approach is not suitable, do you have a brilliant idea I could try instead?

Comment: Use the tufte-book class, it has exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @Yiannis: Thank you! That class looks perfect. Why didn't you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: I thought it was important to point you at the right direction and see if you were comfortable with that, don't worry about points, you can accept N.N's answer. I gave it a click myself also.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As others have said, you can use the `tufte-book` document class. It offers captions in the sidenotes area and a  `fullwidth` environment that stretches across the main text block and the sidenotes area.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{4cm}{2cm}
  \caption{A black rectangle with lots of text so it fills up some space.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{4cm}{2cm}
  \caption{A black rectangle with lots of text so it fills up some space.}
\end{table}
\begin{fullwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

If you don't want to use the `tufte-book` class, then you can use one of the standard ones (`book`, `report`) together with the `geometry` package to change the page layout, the `floatrow` package to have captions in the margins, and the `changepage` package to change the margins for a part of a document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=4cm,marginparwidth=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\floatsetup{margins=hangleft,capposition=beside,
capbesideposition={top,left},floatwidth=\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{4cm}{2cm}
  \caption{A black rectangle with lots of text so it fills up some space.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{4cm}{2cm}
  \caption{A black rectangle with lots of text so it fills up some space.}
\end{table}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

You could also consider using one of the classes from the KOMA-Script bundle (`scrbook`, `scrreprt`) or the `memoir` document class and adapting them to your needs.

Comment: I like the alternatives you presented, but I think tufte-handout is the best match. Thank you! I wish I could accept more than one answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer to your last question:

> If you have the impression that my
>   layout approach is not suitable, do
>   you have a brilliant idea I could try
>   instead?

Maybe [*tufte-latex*](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/) is for you. [Here is an example of a handout](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/tufte-latex/sample-handout.pdf). See that it contains figures and notes in the margin.

Also you may be interested in [classicthesis](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis/) and its derivate [arsclassica](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arsclassica), they have similar features as tufte-latex. The same goes for [Uggedal’s](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1572530). Check out the links for examples of their looks.

Comment: I don't have the impression that this is an answer to my third question, but rather to the first! Yiannis was a bit faster with his comment - I'd like to accept his comment as an answer. I'll see if more suggestions come in.

Comment: @Christoph I understood the question as you asking for a layout you could use instead of the one you tried to construct on your own.

Comment: you understood me correctly! Nonetheless, you answer answers my first question more than my third question, because it doesn't provide an alternative, but exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

> caesar_book.cls

given by the **sidenotes** package.

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sidenotes

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the floatrow package.

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow