# Margin floats and hyperlinks

Tags: floats, hyperref, positioning, marginpar, tufte

I read [Margin Figures/captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/margin-figures-captions) and the answers within. I have stripped the definition of the `marginfloats` from the `tufte` documentclass into the MWE below.

Can the definition of `\@tufte@margin@floatbox` be tweaked so that the hyperlink goes to the top of the figure, and not below the caption?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=6cm,right=1cm,showframe=true,
            asymmetric=true]{geometry}               
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\reversemarginpar
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{5cm}

\makeatletter
% Margin float environment
\newsavebox{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}
\newenvironment{@tufte@margin@float}[2][-1.2ex]%
  {\FloatBarrier% process all floats before this point so the figure/table numbers stay in order.
  \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}%
    \def\@captype{#2}%
    \hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%
    \noindent%
  }
  {\end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \marginpar{\usebox{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}}%
  }

% Margin figure environment
\newenvironment{marginfigure}[1][-1.2ex]%
  {\begin{@tufte@margin@float}[#1]{figure}}
  {\end{@tufte@margin@float}}

% Margin table environment
\newenvironment{margintable}[1][-1.2ex]%
  {\begin{@tufte@margin@float}[#1]{table}}
  {\end{@tufte@margin@float}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a hyperlink to Figure \ref{fig:test}

\newpage

\begin{marginfigure}
 \centering
 \rule{30pt}{20pt}
 \caption{Figure in margin}
 \label{fig:test}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`hypcap` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hypcap) attempts to find "a solution of the problem with hyperref, that links to floats points below the caption and not at the beginning of the float." (taken directly from the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/hypcap.pdf)) Consequently, it provides `\capstart` to denotes the start of floating environment and where the hyperlink should jump to.

```
...
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepacakge{hypcap}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hypcap
...
% Margin figure environment
\newenvironment{marginfigure}[1][-1.2ex]%
  {\begin{@tufte@margin@float}[#1]{figure}%
   \capstart\endgraf}% <-- Hyperlink jumps to start of 'marginfigure'
  {\end{@tufte@margin@float}}

% Margin table environment
\newenvironment{margintable}[1][-1.2ex]%
  {\begin{@tufte@margin@float}[#1]{table}%
   \capstart\endgraf}% <-- Hyperlink jumps to start of 'margintable'
  {\end{@tufte@margin@float}}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the background and detailed answer.

Comment: I actually ended up using `\usepackage[all]{hypcap}` which fixed all of my hyperlinks to floats.

Comment: @cmhughes: This, or something related, is [causing me an error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56955/7844).