# Implementing marginfigure

Tags: floats, margins, marginpar, tufte

sorry for the absolutely beginner question here.

I've been looking at the `tufte-latex` class, specifically the [tufte sample book](https://tufte-latex.googlecode.com/files/sample-book-3.5.0.pdf). It makes use of `marginfigures`, which I believe are provided by the [sidenotes package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sidenotes/sidenotes.pdf).

As you can see in the book, there is a `marginfigure` implemented with the code:

```
\begin{marginfigure}
  \includegraphics{file}
  \caption{caption}
\end{marginfigure}
```

However, in my custom class file I use the `sidenotes` package using

```
\usepackage{sidenotes}
```

It should be noted that this works fine, I can use normal `sidenotes` without any problems.

However, when I go to put in a `marginfigure` using the code above I get the following error:

```
Environment marginfigure undefined. 
\begin{document} ended by \end{marginfigure}
```

How can this be fixed so that my `marginfigure` implements properly. 
Sorry for the basic question, but I hadn't found any other fixes.

EDIT 1:
Those are the only two errors I have.

All I do is import the package in my class file, then in the document I try to implement `marginfigure`, but receive the errors above.

Do I need to use any other packages alongside it?

EDIT 2:MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics{marginfigure}
\end{marginfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: According to the `sidenotes` package documentation, the `marginfigure` example you provided should work fine. The error you provided is usually preceded by other errors that are more indicative of the cause of the problem. Can you provide us a short document that demonstrates this error?

Comment: @godbyk I've just edited the question, but I don't think its what you really want. Sorry I'm new, but could you explain in more detail what you need?

Comment: Please add [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` which _reproduces_ the error/s. In this way documentclass used by you will also be known to others.

Comment: It's hard to tell without a complete MWE... here's a place you can start, which contains the relevant code for `marginfigure` [Margin floats and hyperlinks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27348)

Comment: @texenthusiast There, I've added a MWE, at least for me it reproduces the errors. Thankyou for all the guidance.

Comment: @akuritsu If you include `\listfiles` before `\begin{document}` and compile you can see the list of packages and its version used. If my guess is right your's would be `sidenotes.sty 2011/11/29 v0.81` but your MWE compiles well with `sidenotes.sty 2012/11/09 v0.92`. Hence you may need an [update to your TeX distribution ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/15717) or use latest version of `sidenotes` from ctan. **Reason**: `marginfigure` feature is added in `sidenotes` from v0.90 as seen in [page 6 of Change History](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sidenotes/sidenotes.pdf)

Comment: @texenthusiast That solved the question, if you want to make your comment an answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: @akuritsu Great to know. I have made my comment to answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you include `\listfiles` before `\begin{document}` and compile you can see the list of packages and its version shown below.

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
sidenotes.sty    2012/11/09 v0.92 rich text in the margin for LaTeX
```

you might be using an old version of `sidenotes.sty 2011/11/29 v0.81` which causes the error, because `marginfigure` feature is added in `sidenotes` from `v0.90` as seen in [page 6 of Change History](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sidenotes/sidenotes.pdf). Hence your MWE compiles well with `sidenotes.sty 2012/11/09 v0.92`.

It is recommended to [update to your TeX distribution ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/15717) to keep pace with latex package development or use latest version of [sidenotes from ctan](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes).