# How to leave space on the side of a page for figures

Tags: floats, formatting

I have noticed that a lot of technical books leave room for figures on the left side of the page. The text is on the right, and it is restricted to not take up the entire page width so that there is room for the figures. I like this layout, and would like to use it in my LaTeX documents.

Does anyone know how to format a document like this? For my purposes, I think leaving `0.75\textwidth` for text and the other `0.25\textwidth` for pictures would work fine. I tried to achieve something similar using the `wrapfigure` environment, but I think it would look better if it just had a designated space for pictures (if possible). When I use `wrapfigure` it messes up the alignment of the section headings and text.

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115139/14757

Comment: have a look at the `tufte` document classes

Comment: @cmhughes I looked at it, and it made no sense. At all. I was hoping there would be a way to change the `amsart` document that I already have set up, instead of using a new `\documentclass` that requires completely different commands. Thanks for your input, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`tufte`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex) classes were designed for this purpose (amongst others), so you could give them a try. However, as I see from the comments to the question, you want to stick to `amsart`. As a personal note, I don't understand this: AMS classes were designed for specific typographic needs which don't include what you want, and `tufte` classes already offer you what you want.

Anyway, if you want to (ab)use the AMS classes, you'll have to do some work. One possibility is to take advantage of the space reserved for marginal notes and use the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package to change the page layout adding some additional space to the width reserved for these marginal notes. With the [`marginnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package, you can use \marginnote to typeset the images in the marginal notes area, using `\captionof` (from the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package) to provide captions. A little example that could give you a starting point:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage[rmargin=3cm,textwidth=11cm,marginparwidth=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}

\newcommand\MarginFigure[4][width=4cm]{%
\marginnote{%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
  \captionof{figure}{#3}
  \label{#4}
\end{minipage}}}
\reversemarginpar
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\MarginFigure{example-image-a}{a test figure}{fig:testa}
\lipsum[3-4]
\MarginFigure{example-image-b}{a test figure}{fig:testb}
\lipsum[1-3]
\MarginFigure{example-image-c}{a test figure}{fig:testb}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One more question: Is it possible to put a title centered at the top of the page, outside of the margin formatting?