# How to put figures in the margin beside text?

Tags: floats, margins, marginpar, marginnote

For my thesis, I would like to be able to put some illustrative pictures in the (exterior) margin, beside text as it is the case in following example ([original document](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/pastel-01016795/document), p. 16)

[image: images beside text]

However, I cannot find the keywords that would lead me to an answer (I am stuck in threads about side-by-side figures or text-wrapping).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The package you should take a look at is called `marginnote`. Your PDF has been typeset with pdfLaTeX. You could kindly ask the author for the source code (or parts of it).

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/margin-figures-captions

Comment: Use the `tufte-book` class.

Comment: Technically, a figure is a float and takes up an entire column, but one can always put an image} into a \marginpar or \marginnote.. To include a \captionof{figure} you will need to use \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth} .. \end{minipage} since captions use \par.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi yes I will. `marginnote` seems to be a good start!
@StevenB.Segletes yes it is, thx.
@YiannisLazarides It is the kind of result I'd like to achieve, indeed. However, I'd personnaly like - as far as possible - to remain within Koma-script classes that I begin to master and already pimped a bit.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi : fyi, the presented document has been edited... with MS Word!

Comment: @ebo strange, Two PDF-viewers tell me, is has been done by pdfLaTeX. Maybe HAL is using some conversion tool...

Comment: @LaRiFaRi : I think the first page (same template for each document on HAL) is edited _via_ LaTeX, and the other pages come from the submitted PDF (here created _via_ MS Word, as the author told me per email) using something like `\includepdf`.

Comment: This question have been solved more broadly in [text, margin, and text + margin width floats without using tufte class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301769/64454).